# 'tell me what I should do' vs 'tell me what should I do'

Tags: questions, reported-speech

These are questions and with questions you put the verb first and then the pronoun.

**For example:**

**Affirmative** : You can.

**Question**: Can you?

But sometimes when speaking I hear people not applying this rule.

Maybe it's correct in speech but incorrect in writing?!

> Tell me what **I should** do?
>
> Tell me what **should I** do?
>
> Do you know what **you can** do to...
>
> Do you know what **can you** do to...

Comment: See a related question and a detailed answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24643/27840).

Comment: Yes, that answer is the answer needed here. So this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

As with the difference between *direct* quotes and *indirect* quotes, there is little difference in meaning between these two structures.  The difference is in phrasing and nuance.  The first structure is a straightforward question.  The second structure is more like a quote, as if you asked someone that question directly.

Imagine these written as direct quotes:

> Tell me what I should do?
>   Tell me, "What should I do?"
>
> Do you know what you can do to fix the situation?
>   Do you know, "What can you do to fix the situation?"
>
> Tell me where he goes on Tuesday evenings?
>   Tell me, "Where does he go on Tuesday evenings?"

These kind of inversions are common in English, and are often slightly more formal or literary (or at least *affected*).  They therefore can be more *dramatic* in context.

> "It's not the best solution," he sighed, "but tell me what else **can we do** in times such as these?"

Here the inversion is used as a *rhetorical* device to suggest the person speaking isn't really looking for an answer.  He's just expressing his frustration.  The other phrasing would better indicate that he wants advice:

> "It's not the best solution," he sighed, "but tell me what else **we can do** in times such as these?"